# Identify the plot in this image

Tags: geometry, wolfram-mathematica

I'm not math savvy, but this Mathematica plot caught my eye and I was hoping you could help me identify it.

I've searched the various functions and keywords found in the pictured code, but none of the results suggested anything specific to me about whatever algorithm is at work in this plot.

[image: Screenshot from Mathematica]

Sorry about the quality, it's a screen capture of a video

Comment: There is no image in this picture (all the more reason to not use external links). I'm down voting this and voting to close as 'too localized'. Besides, it's not a question related to programming.

Comment: @yoda I've updated the image path.

Comment: @grough Thanks. I've removed my downvote :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a [Voronoi Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) to me.

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, you're looking at a Voronoi diagram generated by Mathematica.  You can see the Mathematica expression being used, and the key function is [ListDensityPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListDensityPlot.html).

If you follow the latter link and open the "Neat Examples" section you'll see another Voronoi diagram.  The key parameter there is **InterpolationOrder→0**.

Answer (score 1):

Except for the *two* dots in the light-purple area (third from top left), one of which might be a video artifact, every coloured area has a single dot, and points in the field appear (both by looking at the diagram and guessing what the code means) to be coloured according to which of the dots they are closest to.

Which would make it, [as @Moron has said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241698/help-me-identify-the-plot-in-this-image/3241710#3241710), a Voronoi diagram.

Answer (score 1):

True. Voronoi Diagrams can build that sort of "image".

Look for Voronoi Diagrams or Thiessen Polygons.